# How to check whether a server is available for mounting a folder/drive on local netwok?

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I would like to check whether a server is available or not on the local network.
I can connect connect to shared folders with FSMountServerVolumeAsync, but I would like to check their availability before, otherwise OS pops up a message if the server is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are many ways to do so.

One solution would be to simply try creating a connection using NSURLConnection. If it fails (there is a delegate) you know that you don't even have to try to mount it...

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will check it out. I just moved so no internet, no network.